# Remove black border around my text box - outline:none doesn't seem to work

Tags: html, css

I have a text box that dynamically changes length with the text. However, there is an annoying black border around the text box which I would like to remove. [image: Black Border]

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewpoint" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title>TrialV3</title>
    <link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
        <div class="nameone">
            <input class="text" type="text" onkeypress="this.style.width = ((this.value.length + 1)*8 ) + 'px';">
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS Code:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
.nameone {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  border-radius: 5%;
}

.nameone::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 19px;
  right: -13px;
  background: black;
  z-index: 1;
}

.nameone::before {
  content: "+";
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  top: 11px;
  right: -21.5px;
  color: orange;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 2;
}

.text {
    outline:none !important;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

I tried outline: none, outline: transparent, box-shadow: none and nothing works. I even tried to go into the google chrome website editor to try to identify what element is causing it and nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
.nameone {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  border-radius: 5%;
}

.nameone::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 19px;
  right: -13px;
  background: black;
  z-index: 1;
}

.nameone::before {
  content: "+";
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  top: 11px;
  right: -21.5px;
  color: orange;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 2;
}

.text {
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewpoint" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title>TrialV3</title>
    <link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
        <div class="nameone">
            <input class="text" type="text" onkeypress="this.style.width = ((this.value.length + 1)*8 ) + 'px';">
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add "border:none" in the ".text" section of your css?

Comment: Everything but that lol - that's perfect, thanks!!